A lambda function in my state machine fails due to a rate limit error: Status Code: 429; Error: TooManyRequestsException - Concurrency issue?
I built a state machine following this AWS Blog for document classification - However, the state machine is failing at the "Check table status" step due to the error above. I took time googling the error and I see that it is likely that my concurrency limit is too low (for some reason, my ConcurrentExecutions are set at 10 and my UnreservedConcurrentExecutions are also set at 10).
{
    "AccountLimit": {
        "TotalCodeSize": 80530636800,
        "CodeSizeUnzipped": 262144000,
        "CodeSizeZipped": 52428800,
        "ConcurrentExecutions": 10,
        "UnreservedConcurrentExecutions": 10
    },
    "AccountUsage": {
        "TotalCodeSize": 146707791,
        "FunctionCount": 12
    }
}

I am confused by this because all the documentation I have read says that both the CE and UCE's are set at 1000 by default. I have already sent a request to raise my ConcurrentExecution level to 1000, but I just want to make sure that this is actually the reason that my function is failing? If not, what else could be the source of the problem?
Here is the JSON of my state machine - for some of the functions I had to lower the memory size to 3008 from 10240, as the higher limit was not allowed on my account for some reason.
{
  "Comment": "This is your state machine",
  "StartAt": "Create Table & DynamoDB Stream",
  "States": {
    "Create Table & DynamoDB Stream": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:851725561503:function:endpointbuilder-EndpointBuilderFunction1CreateTabl-SW00ttmcfuxQ"
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Next": "Insert Table Rows with Object Keys"
    },
    "Insert Table Rows with Object Keys": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:851725561503:function:endpointbuilder-EndpointBuilderFunction2InsertTabl-NUzVzd87IUfk"
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Next": "Check Table Status"
    },
    "Check Table Status": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:851725561503:function:endpointbuilder-EndpointBuilderFunction4CheckTable-2Dt7kNWQCAw4"
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Next": "Is Table Complete?"
    },
    "Is Table Complete?": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.is_complete",
          "BooleanEquals": true,
          "Next": "Create CSV"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Wait for Object Processing"
    },
    "Wait for Object Processing": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 300,
      "Next": "Check Table Status"
    },
    "Create CSV": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:851725561503:function:endpointbuilder-EndpointBuilderFunction5CreateCSV-hSQVMKW9zCIL"
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Next": "Train Classifier"
    },
    "Train Classifier": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:851725561503:function:endpointbuilder-EndpointBuilderFunction6TrainClass-82V76epxTVTm"
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Next": "Check Classifier Status"
    },
    "Check Classifier Status": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:851725561503:function:endpointbuilder-EndpointBuilderFunction7CheckClass-lTv1oszafKic"
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Next": "Is Training Complete?"
    },
    "Is Training Complete?": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.is_trained",
          "BooleanEquals": true,
          "Next": "Build Endpoint"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Wait for Training"
    },
    "Build Endpoint": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:851725561503:function:endpointbuilder-EndpointBuilderFunction8BuildEndpo-pf3WqV4PbC33"
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Next": "Check Endpoint Status"
    },
    "Check Endpoint Status": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:851725561503:function:endpointbuilder-EndpointBuilderFunction9CheckEndpo-1yGh7iUx8sG1"
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Next": "Is Endpoint Ready?"
    },
    "Is Endpoint Ready?": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.endpoint_is_complete",
          "BooleanEquals": true,
          "Next": "Success"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Wait for Endpoint"
    },
    "Success": {
      "Type": "Succeed"
    },
    "Wait for Endpoint": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 300,
      "Next": "Check Endpoint Status"
    },
    "Wait for Training": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 600,
      "Next": "Check Classifier Status"
    }
  }
}

I have emailed AWS to ask for a raise on my ConcurrentExecution limit and I have googled the error I am currently receiving to look for potential solutions.
